# Polymorphic Destructor: Confusion About What Qualifies As A "Similar" [conv.qual] Types"

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, language-lawyer, destructor

I just read through a rough copy of C++ standard (https://eel.is/c++draft/) and found this in section [expr.delete] paragraph 3:

> In a single-object delete expression, if the static type of the object to be deleted is not similar ([conv.qual]) to its dynamic type and the selected deallocation function is not a destroying operator delete, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined. In an array delete expression, if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted is not similar to its static type, the behavior is undefined.

What does it mean by "not similar"? I looked at [conv.qual], and it's just really confusing stuff about const volatile qualifiers, which I have no idea what they are.

Is a pointer to a base class object "similar" (according to [conv.qual]) to a pointer to a derived class object?

Also, what does it mean by "the selected deallocation function is not a destroying operator delete"? I also did some reading on what a "deallocation function" is, but it was also a bit jargoney...does the default destructor of a class (either base or derived) count as a "destroying operator delete"?

Comment: Presumably that’s defined in `[conv.qual]`. That’s why the cross reference is there.

Comment: I recommend reading [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) instead of standard. It's much easier read and unless you are writing a compiler, you don't need more details. About the "similar" types, it's indeed very legalese - in short, this passage says you are allowed to `Base* b = new Derived; delete b;` (if `~Base()` is `virtual`), but you are not allowed to `Base* b = new Derived[13]; delete[] b;` under any circumstances.

Comment: It's clear from the text of **[expr.delete/3]** that a pointer to base class is **not** similar to a pointer to derived class. Otherwise, the whole "the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type" part would be moot (because this passage is only reached when the static and the dynamic types are not similar).

Answer (score 3):

"Similar" is defined in [conv.qual]. Perhaps it would be easier explained in code:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U> struct is_similar;

template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_similar_nocv : std::is_same<T, U> {};
template<typename T, typename U, std::size_t N>
struct is_similar_nocv<T[N], U[N]> : is_similar<T, U> {};
template<typename T, typename U, std::size_t N>
struct is_similar_nocv<T[N], U[]> : is_similar<T, U> {};
template<typename T, typename U, std::size_t N>
struct is_similar_nocv<T[], U[N]> : is_similar<T, U> {};
template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_similar_nocv<T[], U[]> : is_similar<T, U> {};
template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_similar_nocv<T*, U*> : is_similar<T, U> {};
template<typename T, typename U, typename Class>
struct is_similar_nocv<T Class::*, U Class::*> : is_similar<T, U> {};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_similar : is_similar_nocv<std::remove_cv_t<T>, std::remove_cv_t<U>> {};
```

Basically, the two types are the same disregarding any const/volatile qualifications (and also array bounds can become unknown). Except for the array bounds, these are the types that can be `const_cast` between.

For example:

```cpp
using A1 = int*     ***;
using A2 = int*const***;
// pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer

using B1 = int*const*     (*[2]);
using B2 = int*     *const(*[ ]);
// pointer to an array of pointer to pointers

struct X;
using C1 = int*const* X::* *     *;
using C2 = int*     * X::* *const*;
// pointer to a pointer to a pointer-to-an-X-member which is a pointer to a pointer
```

the corresponding types are similar.

`Base*` is *not* similar to `Derived*`. You would worry about this if you were allocating pointers:

```cpp
Base** p = new Base*(&object);
const Base* const* q = const_cast<const Base* const*>(p);
delete q;  // Valid, *q is of a similar type

p = new Base*(&object);
Derived** r = reinterpret_cast<Derived**>(p);
delete r;  // Invalid, *r is not of a similar type.
```

For non-pointer/array types, "similar" means "the same after remove cv qualifiers".

---

Destroying deletes are a specific form of [`operator delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete): They have an argument of type [`std::destroying_delete_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/destroying_delete).

The reason it's not UB to call delete for the wrong type for a type with a destroying delete is that the delete expression doesn't call the destructor.

For example:

```cpp
struct X {
    ~X();
};

struct Y {
    // destroying delete is responsible for calling the destructor then deallocating memory
    static void operator delete(Y* ptr, std::destroying_delete_t) {
        X* x_ptr = reinterpret_cast<X*>(ptr);
        x_ptr->~X();
        operator delete(x_ptr, sizeof(X));
    }
    ~Y() = delete;
};

int main() {
    Y* p = reinterpret_cast<Y*>(new X);
    delete p;  // Simply calls the destroying deallocation function
    // ::delete p;  // Would select the global deallocation for a type that is not similar, UB
}
```